# Sublime text 2 tail -f in windows

Tags: sublimetext2, tail

I was wondering if sublime text 2 can "tail -f" file like in linux, I'm using windows btw.

I wanted to see apache error log file in xampp.

Notepad++ has it is there a plugin that can do it in sublime text 2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know if it's possible or not, but I usually use **[Baretail](http://www.baremetalsoft.com/baretail/)** which handle pretty well like tail.

The thing I really love with Baretail, is the regex you can define to highlight some part of your log file. Like, put each with line with

- error inside with a red background, bold and white text,
- warning message, with an orange background, italic and white text,
- etc ...

[image]

Otherwise, it seems [you are not the only one](http://sublimetext.userecho.com/topic/98212-a-tail-f-function-would-be-soooo-awesome/) who requested this kind of features (you should upvote the request on *userecho*).

Answer (score 2):

There is a project called [SublimeTail](https://github.com/vifo/SublimeTail) that is currently in development. Currently available to download in Alpha from Github.

Answer (score 0):

For a simple solution, you can use in Windows SO [GNU utilities for Win32](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/).  In this you can find `tail -f` of UNIX/Linux and another useful commands.